# Fastboot flash bootloader fails

Tags: fastboot, cyanogenmod

I tried to install CM11 on my Nexus 10. But, I wasn't able to install the boot.img with fastboot (Rooted, CM11 flashed with Clockworkmod recovery):

`[root@xx temp]# fastboot flash bootloader boot.img
sending 'bootloader' (5100 KB)...
OKAY [  0.708s]
writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote: partition table update fail!)
finished. total time: 0.726s
[root@xx temp]#`

The boot.img is from cm-11-20140405-SNAPSHOT-M5-manta.zip.

Any ideas, why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partition you want to write to is called *boot*, not *bootloader*, so the correct command is

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```